# Restrição Android - 3g

Tags: android

Eu quero restringir o acesso via 3G a um único domínio (o do meu sistema) para economizar o acesso 3G dos funcionários.
Mas se o funcionário acessar via WIFI pode ficar tudo liberado (porque aí nao vai ter custo extra).
Tem algum jeito de fazer isso?

Comment: e um sistema web ou e um aplicativo? Voce quer fazer isto no aplicativo que voce construiu ou voce quer configurar o android?

Comment: De preferência configurar o android... :)

Answer (score 0):

Você pode fazer dessa maneira:

```
    private void setMobileDataEnabled(Context context, boolean enabled) {
        final ConnectivityManager conman = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        final Class conmanClass = Class.forName(conman.getClass().getName());
        final Field iConnectivityManagerField = conmanClass.getDeclaredField("mService");
        iConnectivityManagerField.setAccessible(true);
        final Object iConnectivityManager = iConnectivityManagerField.get(conman);
        final Class iConnectivityManagerClass = Class.forName(iConnectivityManager.getClass().getName());
        final Method setMobileDataEnabledMethod = iConnectivityManagerClass.getDeclaredMethod("setMobileDataEnabled", Boolean.TYPE);
        setMobileDataEnabledMethod.setAccessible(true);

        setMobileDataEnabledMethod.invoke(iConnectivityManager, enabled);
    }
```

E informe esse trecho no seu Manifest:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```

Comment: Valeu! Vou usar isso como Plano B para caso não consiga configurar o android...